# TagHelpers for "older" ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Does anybody knows of anything like the new TagHelpers in upcoming **MVC 6** but for current and previous versions of ASP.NET **MVC <= 5**?

Curiously, jsp (Java EE) supports custom tags since ages but I can't find anything like it for asp.net, that's why I started writing my own TagHelpers library but it's still in early stage, so please let me know if I should stop wasting my time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is nothing like it, check out my own library to support taghelpers in older versions of MVC

nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xania.AspNet.TagHelpers/

codeproject 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/881721/TagHelpers-in-MVC-v-less-than-Next